# How to join two columns from same table and format the new Column in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am very new to SQL and trying to join two columns from the same table and format the result.

The code I have so far is:

```
Select LastName + FirstName as FullName
from Customers
order by FullName
```

The columns I am trying to join are `LastName`, `FirstName`

The result should be formatted as:
FullName in the following format:

> Doe, John

The code should only display results where Last Name is M-Z. Any help is greatly appreciated. I have attached a screenshot below for reference.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/k6qpE.png

Comment: Beware: you are _not_ joining. Join in relation model is between two entities.

Comment: I you're posting code anddata, please don't post images. Both are `text` and you should be posting them as text. Providing images is only likely to have those you are asking help from ignore your question as you are asking them to completely transcribe your information. It is far quicker and easier for you to copy and paste that information than it is for us to type it all out. Thanks.

Comment: `LastName + ', ' + FirstName` should give you the result. But what should happen if the condition is not met? Those rows should be omitted, or you need to display something else?

Comment: You are not joining the columns, you are **_concatenating_** them. Also the software you are using to query your database, i.e. the application that you posted a screen capture of, does allow you to copy the query results to the system clipboard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Select LastName +', '+ FirstName as FullName
from Customers
order by FullName
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use calculated column:

```
CREATE TABLE Customers(LastName NVARCHAR(100), FirstName NVARCHAR(100));
INSERT INTO Customers VALUES ('Doe', 'John'), ('Nagata', 'Naomi');

ALTER TABLE Customers ADD FullName AS (CONCAT(LastName, ', ', FirstName));

Select *
from Customers
where LastName LIKE '[M-Z]%'
order by FullName;
```

**[db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=3025158261fcd5b8f26808b7b4a27d1a)**

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
Select * from (select Firstname + ' ' + Lastname as Fullname from Students) a order by a.Fullname
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select 
    [LastName]+ ', '+[FirstName] as FullName
    from [db]
    where left([LastName],1) in (
    'M',
    'N',
    'O',
    'P',
    'Q',
    'R',
    'S',
    'T',
    'U',
    'V',
    'W',
    'X',
    'Y',
    'Z')

    order by FullName

    ;
```